# Authenticating user with second login

Tags: asp.net, authentication

asp.net I am using a second login control to verify a users email. They will get an Email that directs them to a confirm login window. Not the login that is used in the web.config file. So. I assumed that when they entered the loggedin event the would be authenticated, but it seems they are not. All I want to do here is set the profile property 'confirmed' = Y. So I added code:

```
protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox userName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
    string uname = userName.Text;
    TextBox Password = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName.Text, Password.Text) == true)
    {

        BDrider bd = new BDrider();

        string UserData = bd.getRidFromUsername(uname).ToString();

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, uname, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), false, UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

        Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);


        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Profile.confirmed = "Y";
        }
    Response.Redirect("~/Main/Main.aspx");
    }   
}
```

But on the IsAuthenticated line it returns false ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are creating the cookie and trying to "consume it" in the very same request. Unfortunately, this won't work. The forms authentication module will pick up the cookie and maintain the session starting from just the **next** request.

A possible workaround would be to redirect to an auxiliary page and perform your operation there and then redirect to `Main.aspx`. Your code would be then

```
   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, uname, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), false, UserData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

    Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

    Response.Redirect( "Auxiliary.aspx" );
```

and in the `Auxiliary.aspx`:

```
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Profile.confirmed = "Y";
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/Main/Main.aspx");
```

However, I don't quite get the `if`. If you are just issuing the forms cookie, the user surely **is** authenticated. Why it would be otherwise?